# Position of Percentage Symbol on Keynote Charts

Tags: keynote

I am trying to change percentage symbol on charts in Apple Keynote. Keynote automatically put % symbol before numbers. Is there any way to change/set it as after number? Thank you!

Comment: I am not able to replicate the behavior that you describe.  I am getting rendering like: "100%" in my charts.  Keynote 6.5.3

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the regional settings of your Mac to US. There was an option "US (Computer)". I chose that and it worked.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!   Your answer looks "good" but it should be expanded somewhat.  Consider providing screen shots or references to credible sources  to further expand on what you posted.